# Find the probability that no students from country B are in classroom 2

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations

We have a school with students from countries A and B, 155 and 35 respectively.
We have 4 classrooms that can accommodate 80, 35, 35, 40 students.
If each student is assigned to a class independently and uniformly, compute the probability that classroom 2 has no students from country B.

I have in my mind two possible solutions that reach completely different answers and I don't know which one holds.

1. Each student has probability $3/4$ that he/she does not end up in classroom 2.
   So in total $$p = (3/4)^{35}=0.0000423$$
2. There are $\binom{190}{35}$ in which we can assign students from country B in total and there are $\binom{155}{35}$ ways that we can assign we can assign students from country B in classes except classroom 2 (so in 1, 3, 4).
   $$ p = \frac{C(155, 35)}{C(190, 35)} \approx 0.00035$$
3. There are $C(35+3-1, 35)$ ways to distribute student's of country B to the 3 other classrooms and $C(35+4-1, 35)$ way to distribute them in the 4 classrooms in total.
   $$ p = \frac{C(37, 35)}{C(38, 35)}=0.07894 $$

Comment: Assignments of classrooms are not independent events (if lots of students were already assigned a small classroom, it's less likely that the next assignment will go there).  Thus the first method is wrong.

Comment: @lulu in the statement the assignment of students of country B is independent

Comment: That does not make sense.  There are only $35$ slots for room $B$.  If $30$ have been taken, it is much less likely that the next student will go to room $B$.  If each classroom had at least $190$ slots (so that each room could take *all* the students) then you could have independence.  Here, you clearly can not.

Comment: The best you can do is what you illustrate with the second method.  Sticking to room $B$, you could require that each group of $35$ students is equally likely to end up assigned to room $B$.  That makes sense.  But it is not the same as independence.

Answer (score 2):

Your second approach is correct.  The flaw with your first approach is that placing a student in classroom 2 reduces the probability that another student can be placed in classroom 2.  If there are $a$ seats remaining in classroom 2 and $b$ students left to fill them, where $a < b$, then the probability of a particular student filling a seat in classroom 2 is $a/b$.  Once that slot has been filled, the probability that one of the $b - 1$ remaining students is placed in one of the remaining $a - 1$ seats is $\frac{a - 1}{b - 1}$.  Observe that
$$\frac{a}{b} - \frac{a - 1}{b - 1} = \frac{a(b - 1) - (a - 1)b}{b(b - 1)} = \frac{ab - a - ab + b}{b(b - 1)} = \frac{b - a}{b(b - 1)} > 0$$

Comment: and that holds, even if the staement says that for students of country B assignments are independent?

Comment: As lulu stated in the comments, the assignments cannot be independent since the probability that a person is placed in classroom 2 depends on how many slots are left.

Answer (score 0):

The second solution is correct using the reasoning you gave.

The first solution would be correct if we assumed that all students from class B were assigned one at a time to a classroom at random before those from class A, but it is wrong in this case as it doesn't account for, for example, the possibility of class A filling up any of the rooms before all of class B has been assigned.